# Can I use [strftime] of C++ to do what Java's SimpleDateFormat can do?

Tags: c++14, simpledateformat, strftime

Can I use strftime of C++ to do what Java's Simpledateformat. My format input is the same syntax as SimpleDateFormat but I think I should use strftime because that is the only library I can found that can format datetime.

tz_offset is function that I calculate the timezone

```
   long tz_offset(time_t when)
    {
        if (when == NULL_TIME)
            when = std::time(nullptr);
        auto const tm = *std::localtime(&when);
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << std::put_time(&tm, "%z");
        std::string s = os.str();
        // s is in ISO 8601 format: "±HHMM"
        int h = std::stoi(s.substr(0, 3), nullptr, 10);
        int m = std::stoi(s[0] + s.substr(3), nullptr, 10);

        return h * 3600 + m * 60;
    }
```

This is my format date function

```
 std::string FormatDate(double timestamp, std::string format) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    tm* curr_tm;
    time_t timenum = timestamp / 1000;
    char date_string[100];
    if (format.empty()) {
        int millisecond = timestamp - (long long)((long long)(timestamp / 1000) * 1000);        
        curr_tm = localtime(&timenum);
        strftime(date_string, 50, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.", curr_tm);
        os << date_string << std::to_string(millisecond) << "+0" << std::to_string(tz_offset() / 3600) << "00"; 
        //My output : 2019-11-01T08:44:39.152+0700
    }
    else {
    //what I must do here??
    }   

    return os.str();
}
```

My main class

```
  int main()
    {
        std::string format = "h 'o''cloch' a, zzzz";
        FormatDate(1572492011438, format);
        return 0;
    }
```

What I have done is if format string is empty so I will go straight to my default format. But what about the user input format string. I have think of string replacement function.

```
08 o'clock AM, Indochina Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICU appears to have a parser for the format:
https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1SimpleDateFormat.html#details

EDIT: adding example

```cpp
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
UnicodeString datePattern("h 'o''cloch' a, zzzz", "");
SimpleDateFormat* formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern, status);
UnicodeString formatted;
formatter->format(Calendar::getNow(), formatted, status);
std::string formattedOut;
formatted.toUTF8String(formattedOut);
std::cout << formattedOut << "\n";
```

```sh
$ g++ icu.cpp -licuuc -licui18n
$ ./a.out
12 o'cloch AM, GMT-05:00
```

Comment: Can you show me the step or the library where SimpleDateFormat format the pattern? I understand the format syntax of Java's SimpleDateFormat but I want to know where they format the pattern into "something".

Comment: Which library are you using? I'm a newbie to C++, is it C++14 Standard Library only?? Because I'm not allowed to use other open source or higher versions of C++, it's a part of my business rule.

Comment: It would be nice if your code work, it would be a perfect solution for me.

Comment: This is ICU, the official library from the Unicode group for handling text and internationalization. It's pretty old and cross-platform. I'm sure it still works on C++98. 

On Debian you can install it with `sudo apt-get install ilbicu-dev`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I appreciate your help, despite the fact that I don't know how to install the lib :((.

Comment: If you're using Windows + MSVC, use the nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Icu4c.Win.Full.Lib/62.1.4-beta. If you've got a mac, I don't really know.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot mate. But it seems not like a C++ standard library when I include the header it must be a part of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header.